# How do I determine whether a quest belongs to the main story line?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I've heard that there is a main story line in Skyrim, and that you have the main quests and procedurally generated quests besides that. How can I identify whether a quest belongs to the main story line, or whether it is procedurally generated by someone.

I would somehow like to focus on finishing the main story line first...

Comment: Not exactly straightforward, but I believe the "decorations" on either side of the quest title when you're looking at the quest details in your log are type/line-specific.  If someone doesn't beat me to it, I'll see if I can dig up some specifics when I get home tonight.

Comment: Good question, I'd like to know for the opposite reasons, even though I know you can continue on after the main quest. Just been keeping myself busy exploring, working on side quests, and picking flowers

Comment: Like Ben said there are some decorations in the quest description that only appear in main story line quests.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Quests can belong to one of several categories which give them [unique "knotwork"](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Quests#Knotwork) in the journal.  The main quest is one such category, and has knotwork depicting a dragon breathing fire:

[image: main quest knotwork]

Answer (score 8):

There are 19 individual quests making up Skyrim's main quest. They are as follows:

- **Unbound**
- **Before the Storm**
- **Bleak Falls Barrow**
- **Dragon Rising**
- **The Way of the Voice**
- **The Horn of Jurgen Windcaller**
- **A Blade in the Dark**
- **Diplomatic Immunity**
- **A Cornered Rat**
- **Alduin's Wall**
- **The Throat of the World**
- **Elder Knowledge**
- **Alduin's Bane**
- **Season Unending**
- **Paarthurnax**
- **The Fallen**
- **The World-Eater's Eyrie**
- **Sovngarde**
- **Dragonslayer**

The name of the quest is found in your journal. (Quest summaries redacted to avoid spoilers)

Answer (score 3):

Here is a list of the main story line quests.

**Don't delve too far into this page if you don't like spoilers**

http://au.ign.com/wikis/the-elder-scrolls-5-skyrim/Main_Quests

Answer (score 2):

The main quest line has a decoration in the shape of a dragon head, dark brotherhood quests have a skull, deadric quests have the oblivion symbol. The thieves guilds quests have a odd sort of design maybe a lockpick? But the other side quests have a plain decoration.